# Tetris Timer is not working

Tags: c#

I am trying to write Tetris in c#. The speed of the first block is normal, but the second block falling two times quicker than the first one, then the third block is three times quicker. I think there must be something wrong with the timer.

Here is part of my code:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /* ... Some code ... */

    Watch().Start();
}

public Timer Watch()
{
    timer.Stop();
    timer.Interval = 1000;
    timer.Enabled = true;

    /* ... Some code ... */

    // Check if the block can fall down
    if (CheckDown() == true)
    {
        timer.Tick += (sender, e) => timer_Tick(sender, e, Current_sharp.sharp);
    }

    return timer;
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e, Sharp sharp)
{
    if (CheckDown())
    {
        /* ... Some code ... */
    }
    else
    {
        Watch().Start();
    }
}
```

Can anybody tell me why this happens?

Comment: Perhaps you're adding another timer each time a new block is dropped, but not removing the old one?

Comment: Probably comes from this line : `timer.Tick += (sender, e) => timer_Tick(sender, e, Current_sharp.sharp);` You are adding a new EventHandler at each verification. So the code gets executed twice at the 2nd check, and so on.

Comment: that is what I am thinking too, so I added timer.stop() at the beginning, but it didn't work, other way to drop the old timer?

Comment: You don't need to drop the old timer.  It's still there and the event handler is still registered.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault do you know how to fix it, I am still not very clear about the timer EventHandler, thanks

Comment: Hm, with the code shown it's quite complicated to understand the full logic. However, from what I'm seeing, I'd say your `if (CheckDown)` in `Watch` is useless; you're already performing it on each Tick, it is not necessary to redo the same logic there. If you remove it, it will prevent you from adding more handlers (so duplicate the calls). You could probably remove the Watch.Start from timer_tick too, as the timer won't stop anyway. But more code would be nice, hard to grasp completely what is going on there. Not sure if it will work with what you have, but you can try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your function `Watch()`.

Event's can have multiple functions called every time they are fired, that is why it uses the `+=` sign and not the `=` sign. Every time you call `timer.Tick += (sender, e) => timer_Tick(sender, e, Current_sharp.sharp);` you are adding an additional call to `timer_Tick` to the queue.

So the first time `timer_Tick` gets called one time, it then re-registers the handler then the 2nd time around `timer_Tick` gets called twice, and it adds 2 more firings to the queue (making it 4)... and so on.

Without seeing the entire code here is the best I can think of to fix the problem. All I did was move the `timer.Tick` registration from `Watch()` to `Form1_Load()`

```
Timer timer = new Timer();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /* ... Some code ... */

    //regester the event handler here, and only do it once.
    timer.Tick += (sender, e) => timer_Tick(sender, e, Current_sharp.sharp);

    Watch().Start();
}

public Timer Watch()
{
    timer.Stop();
    timer.Interval = 1000;
    timer.Enabled = true;

    /* ... Some code ... */


    return timer;
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e, Sharp sharp)
{
    if (CheckDown())
    {
        /* ... Some code ... */
    }
    else
    {
        Watch().Start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem (might be) here:

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e, Sharp sharp)
{


    if (CheckDown())
    {
        Some code.....

    }
    else
    {
        Watch().Start();
    }

    //throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

I don't know exactly the logic behind your CheckDown() but I assume it returns false* when the block touches down?  In which case every time a block falls it creates a new timer, while you already have a timer running from Form1_Load()...hence why you see the progressive increase in speeds.

Comment: It's not `CheckDown()`, its `Watch()`

Comment: I'm not following you @ScottChamberlain

Comment: Every call of `Watch()` adds another event listener to `timer.Tick`. `Watch()` is called from `timer_Tick` therefor `timer_Tick` gets called twice as many times every call.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're executing this:

```
timer.Tick += ...
```

many times *for each* block?

It seems that that should be in the constructor. And where it's now: just have:

```
if(...)
   timer.Enabled = true;
else
   timer.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: @ScottChamberlain As far as I can tell this is the answer to `Can anybody tell me why this happens?`. My reason for saying `Maybe` is because there's not enough code to be sure of that.

Comment: There is enough code, I just am trying to figure out how to explain it for a answer.